# Use Popen utility in subprocess to run a system command

Tags: python-3.x

how can a define a function which accepts a system command, runs a command in a background and return a result.

```
def run_process(cmd_args):
    with open("echo",cmd_args) as p:
        result = p.communicate()
    return print(result)
```

not getting a desired result.

Comment: `print()` always return None. If you want get the result remove the `print()` command.